# AWS/Step function: Access passed-over header value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have python code to trigger a step function, and pass in custom headers.

```
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn=stateMachineArn,
    name=name,
    input={'id': 'my-id'},
    headers={'mode': 'normal'}
)
```

I have a step inside the step function to trigger a lambda:

```
"trigger-lambda": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:...:function:my-lambda",
    "Parameters": {
        "id.$": "$.id"
    }
}
```

I can access the "id" from the step function's input. But  how to pass "mode" back to the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Step Functions [Start Execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html) does not support a request parameter called headers. You need to include this information in the input if you want it to be available within your workflow. Something like this:

```
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn=stateMachineArn,
    name=name,
    input={'id': 'my-id','mode': 'normal'},
    headers={'mode': 'normal'}
)
```

and then:

```
"trigger-lambda": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:...:function:my-lambda",
    "Parameters": {
        "id.$": "$.id",
        "mode.$: "$.mode"
    }
}
```